# UIStackView with Size Class

Tags: ios, ios9, uistackview

I looked at UIStackView and I don't understand how it can be used with the Resize Class.
I would like to have a imageView and a textView inside stackView in vertical (portrait) mode. I would also like to have the same thing, but in horizontal (landscape) mode.

I can detect the rotation and I change the orientation of the stack. Is this correct?

Comment: you looked at it and you didnt try?

Comment: I tried and I had success. But, I want to know what is the best way.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like this. You don't have to detect any kind of rotation. You just need to *configure*/*constrain* your UIStackViews (or other views) correctly. If you have a specific situation, I can help you

Comment: Are you using storyboard or code to set up the stack view?

Comment: Is storyboard. I not have specific situation! Tks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to change your stack view between portrait and landscape mode using size classes is the following:

1. Select your stack view in storyboard and look at the attribute inspector:
   [image]
2. Click on the plus button next to the attribute you want to change when in landscape and select any width, compact height:
   [image]
3. Finally, set the attribute for what you want when the device is rotated for instance:
   [image]

Hope this answers your question. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Rob, You really helped.
In the end of  this tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views) explains this too.